# Jquery Submit Form to Self

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

In PHP I have a form with 4 Submits. Each submit button has a unique ID, name and value.

When you click button A the value for A is submitted, click button B and it's value is submitted.

I'm trying to replicate this in jquery but as 4 unique events.
So clicking button A pops up a confirmation to advise A has been clicked, I'd then like to submit the page back to itself to read the value of what was submitted.

I need the value of 'A', or 'B' etc and a hidden field.

I've tried :

```
$('#test').submit(function(event){
  $.post("test.php", {'A': "AVALUE", 'hidden_field','Value' }, function(){ 
  });
  return false;
});
```

But this doesn't cause the page to submit and reload.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

could you change the unique id/name to same id/name then give different values to the buttons. if its not working create each java-script action listener for each button and read values.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
form.onsubmit = function() {
    form.target = '_self';
};

document.getElementById('A').onclick = function() {
    form.target = '_blank';
    form.submit();
}
```